# Queue of Main Looper

Tags: android

How can I track a queue of Looper of UI thread Android? I would like to track it for debug purposes. For example, I would like turn on the logging in Looper.loop():

```
        final Printer logging = me.mLogging;
        if (logging != null) {
            logging.println(">>>>> Dispatching to " + msg.target + " " +
                    msg.callback + ": " + msg.what);
        }
```

What's the proper way to assign a Printer to mLogging?  When in the Android Activity lifecycle should it be assigned?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what you are even trying to ask, but it sounds like you should use a debugger, or logger.

Comment: `How can I track a queue of Looper of UI thread Android?` - Have you looked at the `Looper` class for ideas?

Comment: The queue you are looking for is the queue from the Looper returned by `Looper.mylooper()`. So you can look at that looper and look at the queue from that looper.

Answer (score 1):

did you check the official docs? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Seems that something as simple as

```
Looper.getMainLooper().setMessageLogging(new LogPrinter(Log.DEBUG, TAG));
```

would do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the ">>>>> Dispatching to " messages logged by calling the following at the end of my main Activity's onCreate() method:

```
PrintWriterPrinter out= new PrintWriterPrinter(new PrintWriter(System.out,true));
getMainLooper().setMessageLogging(out);
```

Source: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.util.PrintWriterPrinter